# AggregatorFactoryBean - set empty CorrelationStrategy

Tags: spring-integration

How can I configure `AggregatorFactoryBean` to group all messages without  CorrelationStrategy (tried with empty string) or strategy that groups everything ?

I don't have common field or header.

As I don't care about groups but bulks of messages.

I found only dirty solution to pass correlationStrategy method that returns empty string.

```
   AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorFactoryBean = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
   
   aggregatorFactoryBean.setMethodName("aggregatingMethod");
   aggregatorFactoryBean.setCorrelationStrategy(new MethodInvokingCorrelationStrategy(aggregator,"correlateBy"));
   //not working->   // aggregatorFactoryBean.setCorrelationStrategy(new ExpressionEvaluatingCorrelationStrategy(""));
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(10));

   aggregatorFactoryBean.setCorrelationStrategy(new MethodInvokingCorrelationStrategy(aggregator,"correlateBy"));


    class MyAggregator {
        public  List<Item> aggregatingMethod(List<List<Item>> items) {
           return ...
        }

      public String correlateBy(Item item) {
        return "";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CorrelationStrategy` is a `@FunctionalInterface` so there is just enough to have a simple lambda with a constant to produce:

```
aggregatorFactoryBean.setCorrelationStrategy(message -> 1);
```

and it will aggregate all the messages to the same group.

On the other hand if you are talking about only a buffering messages instead of correlating them somehow and processing individualy, you probably better to think to use a `QueueChannel` which would really store sent messages. And whenever you need to take a current buffer for processing, you call its `clear()` which returns for your a `List<Message<?>>`.

Comment: Well, I want to control the number of messages in group, and duration of timeout until release. And maybe in future I will correlate based on some criteria. thanks